# Colorer Plugin in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I've been unable to get the wonderful Eclipse Colorer plugin to work with my current copy of Eclipse (Helios 64 bit).  It installs ok but whenever I attempt to open a source file I get this error:

Error in initialization of native part of the Colorer library. This can be caused by absent net_sf_colorer.dll (libnet_sf_colorer.so) library in paths of java machine. Or, colorer can't find catalog.xml file, which must be placed in '%PLUGIN_DIR%'/colorer/catalog.xml'
Could not initialize class net.sf.colorer.ParserFactory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the version of Eclipse. Try a 32-bit Version, AFAIK Eclipse Colorer has no support for 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to make it run on a 64bit eclipse (indigo) by compiling my own version of Colorer. Once you know it's pretty easy: first you get the svn version:

```
svn co https://colorer.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/colorer/trunk/ trunk
cd trunk/eclipsecolorer/libnative
mkdir objs # not sure why make cannot do that..
make -f makefile.macos_64
```

Then you must create a new x86_64 directory in your eclipse plugin, and copy the lib there. In my case it was:

```
mkdir /Applications/eclipse/plugins/net.sf.colorer_0.9.8/os/macosx/x86_64
cp libnet_sf_colorer.jnilib /Applications/eclipse/plugins/net.sf.colorer_0.9.8/os/macosx/x86_64/
```